# Why does Keras uses searchsorted of the target feature in binary classification?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

On [keras source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py#L198), when preparing the data coming from sklearn to be fitted, we read:

```
if len(y.shape) == 2 and y.shape[1] > 1:
    self.classes_ = np.arange(y.shape[1])
elif (len(y.shape) == 2 and y.shape[1] == 1) or len(y.shape) == 1:
    self.classes_ = np.unique(y)
    y = np.searchsorted(self.classes_, y)
else:
    raise ValueError('Invalid shape for y: ' + str(y.shape))
```

The first `if` is for multiclass classification, the first `elif` is for binary classification. What I do not understand is why is the line

```
y = np.searchsorted(self.classes_, y)
```

needed. Isn't `lambda x: np.searchsorted(np.unique(x), x)` the identity function?

Comment: `y` does not need to be sorted or unique...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't lambda x: np.searchsorted(np.unique(x), x) the identity function?

Only if `y` contains only `0` and `1`. Calling these functions ensures that the final `y` will only contains `0` and `1`, independently of the symbols used to represent the presence or absence of the binary class; for example, some input could express this with `-1` and `1` instead, or something else.

I don't think that, as you say, the first branch of the condition is for multiclass problems and the second one for binary problems. I think the second branch can also be for multiclass problems where the classes are expressed as numbers, instead of one-hot encoded. In this case, again, this preprocessing would allow you to use arbitrary symbols (e.g. arbitrary non-sequential positive and negative integers) for the class and "translate" them into the range `[0, num_classes - 1]`.